# How To Use Ajax in Spring Portlet?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, maven, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm using liferay 6.2 CE ga4, and using Maven (MVC).

Here's my code :

Country:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="select">Select Country</option>
<option value="india">India</option>
<option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>

State:
<select id="state" name="state">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#country" ).change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            url: "${findState}" ,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype:'json',
            data: "countryName="+country ,
            success: function(data){
                $('#state').html('');
                $.each(content, function(i, state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>').text(state.name).attr('value', state.stateId));
                });
            }
        });
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Here's my Java :

```
     @ResourceMapping(value="findState")
     public void findStateForCountry(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException  {
         String countryName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "countryName");
         System.out.println("name="+countryName);
         String name = request.getParameter("countryName");
         System.out.println("name2="+name);
         //var countryName and var name allways NULL

        JSONArray stateArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
        JSONObject stateObject,stateObject2;
        if(countryName.equalsIgnoreCase("india"))
        {
            stateObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            stateObject.put("stateId", "1");
            stateObject.put("name", "Delhi");

            stateObject2 = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            stateObject2.put("stateId", "2");
            stateObject2.put("name", "Gujrat");
        }
        else{

            stateObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            stateObject.put("stateId", "21");
            stateObject.put("name", "LA");

            stateObject2 = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            stateObject2.put("stateId", "22");
            stateObject2.put("name", "California");
        }
        stateArray.put(stateObject);
        stateArray.put(stateObject2);
        response.getWriter().println(stateArray);
     }
```

I want to use pass parameter but it's not working. I use this:

```
String countryName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "countryName");
```

And this:

```
String name = request.getParameter("countryName");
```

To get the parameter but they always got `NULL`.

There's something wrong with my code ?

---

The Answer is :

> Use this in you'r liferay-portlet.xml
>
> ```
> <portlet>
>       <portlet-name>welcome</portlet-name>
>       <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
>   </portlet>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way could be using query string parameters:

```
$( "#country" ).change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            url: "${findState}"+'&countryName='+ country,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype:'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#state').html('');
                $.each(content, function(i, state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>').text(state.name).attr('value', state.stateId));
                });
            }
        });
  }); 
});
```

Then, in your controller, you can use the @RequestParam annotation like this:

```
 @ResourceMapping(value="findState")
 public void findStateForCountry(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "countryName") String countryName) throws IOException  {
     System.out.println("name="+countryName);

    JSONArray stateArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
    JSONObject stateObject,stateObject2;
    if(countryName.equalsIgnoreCase("india"))
    {
        stateObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        stateObject.put("stateId", "1");
        stateObject.put("name", "Delhi");

        stateObject2 = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        stateObject2.put("stateId", "2");
        stateObject2.put("name", "Gujrat");
    }
    else{

        stateObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        stateObject.put("stateId", "21");
        stateObject.put("name", "LA");

        stateObject2 = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
        stateObject2.put("stateId", "22");
        stateObject2.put("name", "California");
    }
    stateArray.put(stateObject);
    stateArray.put(stateObject2);
    response.getWriter().println(stateArray);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL assignment like below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$( "#country" ).change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            url: '<portlet:resourceURL var="findState"></portlet:resourceURL>' ,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype:'json',
            data: "countryName="+country ,
            success: function(data){
                $('#state').html('');
                $.each(content, function(i, state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>').text(state.name).attr('value', state.stateId));
                });
            }
        });
  }); 
});
```